# Create loop on subsets

Tags: r

I work on a bid data frame and I wanna create some actions on subset that I had already create with copy/paste because I understand nothing about loop...

But now I really need to understand how loop because my subsets need's become to be very giant.

I try something with just two subset for training, I do exactly the same actions with loop and without, but there is error messagewith loop way. I create the subsets with a global data frame, there are not from different files.

```
> file=c("M.splendens","G.pulchellus")
> species=c("M.splendens","G.pulchellus")
> for (i in 1:length(species))
+ {
+   data= file[i]
+   data= select(file[i], code_site,passage,adulte)
+   data= spread(passage, adulte)
+   data= replace(data, is.na(data),0)
+   title=(species[i])
+   }
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"
> data = M.splendens
> data = select(data, code_site,passage,adulte)
> data = spread(data, passage, adulte)
> data = replace(data, is.na(data),0)
> M.splendens_td_a = data
```

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you in advance for your help.

Have a nice day !

Théodore

Comment: Both *file* and *species* are equivalent character vectors. Where is the dataframe(s)?

Comment: dataframes are in my global environment.

Comment: Do not quote them then in *file* object.